# Is it posssible to use Poledia/react-native-ble-plx to turn iOS device into iBeacon?

Tags: ios, react-native, frameworks, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

I'm developing an app in React Native for iOS and Android,
it will use BLE to emit an UUID for an external device to find. 
The other device functions as the central.

So is it possible to use [Poledia/react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) to set the device in peripheral-mode, and make it a beacon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [React-native-ibeacon-simulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibeacon-simulator). Works great!